# path one level too low in python console of pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am working on my first major python app and am having some trouble with the environment.  I am trying to use python console (in pycharm). When I fire off the console, I get this -

```
sys.path.extend(['/home/scphantm/code/gitflow_plus', '/home/scphantm/code/gitflow_plus/gitflow', '/home/scphantm/code/gitflow_plus/bin', '/home/scphantm/code/gitflow_plus/tests'])
```

when i do this -

```
>>> sys.path
    ['/usr/local/pycharm/helpers/pydev', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/GitPython-0.3.2.RC1-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gitdb-0.5.4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/smmap-0.8.2-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/async-0.6.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/home/scphantm/code/gitflow_plus', '/home/scphantm/code/gitflow_plus/gitflow', '/home/scphantm/code/gitflow_plus/bin', '/home/scphantm/code/gitflow_plus/tests']
```

now if I try to do an import for one of my project files, i have to do, for example

```
import gitflow.conf.configmanager
```

instead of simply

```
import conf.configmanager
```

The problem of this is config manager has imports that are relative to the gitflow folder and those fail to be found.

I supposed what im asking for is whats the command to tell python console to effectively go

```
cd gitflow
```

**** a bit more info

```
>>> os.getcwd()
'/home/scphantm/Code/gitflow_plus/gitflow'
>>> from conf.configmanager import ConfigManager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named configmanager
```

**** directory structure

```
gitflow_plus (project root folder)
  bin
  gitflow
    bin
    conf
       __init__.py
       configmanager.py
         class ConfigManager
    __init__.py
    exceptions.py
      class exception1
      class exception2
      class exception3
  tests
    fixtures
    gitflow
    helpers
    usecase
```

================== more trying

I have been reading up and I found this stuff:

```
>>> __name__
'__main__'
>>> __package__
>>> __package__ = 'gitflow'
>>> from conf.configmanager import ConfigManager
/usr/local/pycharm/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py:1: RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'gitflow' not found while handling absolute import
  try:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named conf.configmanager
```

================
yet more info

```
>>> import conf.configmanager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named configmanager
>>> dir(conf)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'conf' is not defined
>>> dir(gitflow)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'gitflow' is not defined
>>> import gitflow.conf.configmanager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/scphantm/code/gitflow_plus/gitflow/conf/configmanager.py", line 7, in <module>
    from exceptions import NoRepositoryObject
ImportError: cannot import name NoRepositoryObject
>>> dir(sys)
['__displayhook__', '__doc__', '__egginsert', '__excepthook__', '__name__', '__package__', '__plen', '__stderr__', '__stdin__', '__stdout__', '_clear_type_cache', '_current_frames', '_getframe', '_mercurial', '_multiarch', 'api_version', 'argv', 'builtin_module_names', 'byteorder', 'call_tracing', 'callstats', 'copyright', 'displayhook', 'dont_write_bytecode', 'exc_clear', 'exc_info', 'exc_type', 'excepthook', 'exec_prefix', 'executable', 'exit', 'flags', 'float_info', 'float_repr_style', 'getcheckinterval', 'getdefaultencoding', 'getdlopenflags', 'getfilesystemencoding', 'getprofile', 'getrecursionlimit', 'getrefcount', 'getsizeof', 'gettrace', 'hexversion', 'last_traceback', 'last_type', 'last_value', 'long_info', 'maxint', 'maxsize', 'maxunicode', 'meta_path', 'modules', 'path', 'path_hooks', 'path_importer_cache', 'platform', 'prefix', 'py3kwarning', 'pydebug', 'setcheckinterval', 'setdlopenflags', 'setprofile', 'setrecursionlimit', 'settrace', 'stderr', 'stdin', 'stdout', 'subversion', 'version', 'version_info', 'warnoptions']
```

=======================
hey, small breakthru.  I took a step back and considered maybe the word 'conf' is a reserved word or a package that already exists somewhere.  so I renamed it config.  now, I get

```
>> import config.configmanager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/scphantm/code/gitflow_plus/gitflow/config/configmanager.py", line 7, in <module>
    from exceptions import NoRepositoryObject
ImportError: cannot import name NoRepositoryObject
```

Now, from the directory structure you see above, you see exceptions is in the root of the project.  why would it now be able to find the module and class, but the module code not be able to find something in the root?

================================
you guys can pull my project if you want to give a crack at it.  its at

```
git@github.com:scphantm/gitflow_plus.git
```

im still stumped.

===============
I am still learning commands.  when i do this

```
>>>sys.modules
{'heapq': <module 'heapq' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/heapq.pyc'>, 'code': <module 'code' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/code.pyc'>, 'distutils': <module 'distutils' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/__init__.pyc'>, 'functools': <module 'functools' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/functools.pyc'>, 'random': <module 'random' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/random.pyc'>, 'datetime': <module 'datetime' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>, 'sysconfig': <module 'sysconfig' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.pyc'>, 'encodings.encodings': None, 'xml': <module 'xml' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/__init__.pyc'>, 'struct': <module 'struct' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/struct.pyc'>, 'tempfile': <module 'tempfile' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.pyc'>, 'base64': <module 'base64' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/base64.pyc'>, 'pyexpat.errors': <module 'pyexpat.errors' (built-in)>, 'collections': <module 'collections' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/collections.pyc'>, 'distutils.types': None, 'zipimport': <module 'zipimport' (built-in)>, 'string': <module 'string' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/string.pyc'>, 'SocketServer': <module 'SocketServer' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py'>, 'encodings.utf_8': <module 'encodings.utf_8' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc'>, 'ssl': <module 'ssl' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.pyc'>, 'distutils.re': None, 'httplib': <module 'httplib' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.pyc'>, 'config.exceptions': None, 'signal': <module 'signal' (built-in)>, 'threading': <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'>, 'pyexpat.model': <module 'pyexpat.model' (built-in)>, 'distutils.version': <module 'distutils.version' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/version.pyc'>, 'cStringIO': <module 'cStringIO' (built-in)>, 'pygit2.repository': <module 'pygit2.repository' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygit2/repository.pyc'>, 'xml.parsers.expat': <module 'xml.parsers.expat' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/parsers/expat.pyc'>, 'encodings': <module 'encodings' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc'>, 'BaseHTTPServer': <module 'BaseHTTPServer' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py'>, 'pydev_imports': <module 'pydev_imports' from '/usr/local/pycharm/helpers/pydev/pydev_imports.pyc'>, 'config.distutils': None, 'abc': <module 'abc' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/abc.pyc'>, 'rfc822': <module 'rfc822' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/rfc822.pyc'>, 'urllib': <module 'urllib' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.pyc'>, 're': <module 're' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/re.pyc'>, 'math': <module 'math' (built-in)>, 'fcntl': <module 'fcntl' (built-in)>, 'UserDict': <module 'UserDict' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.pyc'>, 'Queue': <module 'Queue' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/Queue.pyc'>, 'codecs': <module 'codecs' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc'>, '_sysconfigdata_nd': <module '_sysconfigdata_nd' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu/_sysconfigdata_nd.pyc'>, '_functools': <module '_functools' (built-in)>, 'socket': <module 'socket' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.pyc'>, 'thread': <module 'thread' (built-in)>, 'StringIO': <module 'StringIO' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/StringIO.pyc'>, 'traceback': <module 'traceback' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/traceback.pyc'>, 'itertools': <module 'itertools' (built-in)>, 'config.os': None, 'os': <module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>, '__future__': <module '__future__' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/__future__.pyc'>, '_collections': <module '_collections' (built-in)>, '_sre': <module '_sre' (built-in)>, '__builtin__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, 'xml.parsers': <module 'xml.parsers' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/parsers/__init__.pyc'>, 'operator': <module 'operator' (built-in)>, 'xml.parsers.pyexpat': None, 'array': <module 'array' (built-in)>, 'distutils.string': None, 'select': <module 'select' (built-in)>, '_heapq': <module '_heapq' (built-in)>, 'posixpath': <module 'posixpath' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>, 'errno': <module 'errno' (built-in)>, '_socket': <module '_socket' (built-in)>, 'binascii': <module 'binascii' (built-in)>, 'sre_constants': <module 'sre_constants' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.pyc'>, 'os.path': <module 'posixpath' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>, 'config.pygit2': None, '_warnings': <module '_warnings' (built-in)>, 'pygit2._pygit2': None, 'encodings.__builtin__': None, '_codecs': <module '_codecs' (built-in)>, 'SimpleXMLRPCServer': <module 'SimpleXMLRPCServer' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/SimpleXMLRPCServer.py'>, 'pydev_console_utils': <module 'pydev_console_utils' from '/usr/local/pycharm/helpers/pydev/pydev_console_utils.pyc'>, '_sysconfigdata': <module '_sysconfigdata' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc'>, '_struct': <module '_struct' (built-in)>, 'hashlib': <module 'hashlib' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.pyc'>, 'keyword': <module 'keyword' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/keyword.pyc'>, 'zlib': <module 'zlib' (built-in)>, 'posix': <module 'posix' (built-in)>, 'encodings.aliases': <module 'encodings.aliases' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.pyc'>, 'exceptions': <module 'exceptions' (built-in)>, 'sre_parse': <module 'sre_parse' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.pyc'>, 'mimetools': <module 'mimetools' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/mimetools.pyc'>, 'copy_reg': <module 'copy_reg' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc'>, 'sre_compile': <module 'sre_compile' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc'>, '_hashlib': <module '_hashlib' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>, '_random': <module '_random' (built-in)>, 'site': <module 'site' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site.pyc'>, 'io': <module 'io' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/io.pyc'>, '__main__': <module '__main__' from '/usr/local/pycharm/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py'>, 'pyexpat': <module 'pyexpat' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>, 'urlparse': <module 'urlparse' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/urlparse.pyc'>, 'strop': <module 'strop' (built-in)>, 'linecache': <module 'linecache' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/linecache.pyc'>, 'encodings.codecs': None, '_abcoll': <module '_abcoll' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc'>, 'config': <module 'config' from '/home/scphantm/code/gitflow_plus/gitflow/config/__init__.pyc'>, 'pygit2': <module 'pygit2' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygit2/__init__.pyc'>, 'genericpath': <module 'genericpath' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc'>, 'stat': <module 'stat' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/stat.pyc'>, '_ssl': <module '_ssl' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>, 'warnings': <module 'warnings' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc'>, 'pydevd_constants': <module 'pydevd_constants' from '/usr/local/pycharm/helpers/pydev/pydevd_constants.pyc'>, 'encodings.ascii': <module 'encodings.ascii' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/ascii.pyc'>, 'pydev_localhost': <module 'pydev_localhost' from '/usr/local/pycharm/helpers/pydev/pydev_localhost.pyc'>, 'textwrap': <module 'textwrap' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/textwrap.pyc'>, 'sys': <module 'sys' (built-in)>, 'codeop': <module 'codeop' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/codeop.pyc'>, 'pygit2.string': None, 'types': <module 'types' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/types.pyc'>, '_pygit2': <module '_pygit2' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pygit2.so'>, 'sitecustomize': <module 'sitecustomize' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/sitecustomize.pyc'>, '_weakref': <module '_weakref' (built-in)>, 'pygit2.version': <module 'pygit2.version' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygit2/version.pyc'>, 'xmlrpclib': <module 'xmlrpclib' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.pyc'>, '_io': <module '_io' (built-in)>, '_weakrefset': <module '_weakrefset' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc'>, 'time': <module 'time' (built-in)>, 'gzip': <module 'gzip' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.pyc'>}
```

big long thing, but the interesting thing is this line

```
'exceptions': <module 'exceptions' (built-in)>
```

the funny thing is the file that contains all my exceptions is also called exceptions.  as soon as i renamed that file to flow_exceptions, everything lit up and worked just fine.  Well that only took half the day  =-)

Comment: [This is a link](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/import.html) for import using Python 3.3, and [here is the same link](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/modules.html) for Python 2.7.  

Could you show the relevant directory structure?

Comment: there ya go.  if you need any other info let me know.  im just spinning my wheels here

Comment: What doesn't work for you _does_ work for me.  Are you using Python 2.7?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what's going on.  It worked when I tested it on Python 2.7 as well.  Hopefully a true Pythonista can help you out here.

Comment: yea im stumped too.  I dropped out of pycharm and went to a command line and im getting the same thing.  im reading up on __init__.py files.  maybe im doing something odd there.

Comment: `__init__.py` files are called when you import a package -- so if you import `conf`, the `__init__.py` file will be run first.  You can also do special things, like set what happens when you say `from conf import *`.  You can set what actually gets imported.  I haven't used it much, but I hope that helps at all.

Comment: so does the gitflow/__init__.py have to have some kind of reference to conf to be seen or is that done implicitly?

Comment: Ah, so the problem was that you named a module `exceptions.py`!  Get rid of the part where you explain that in the question, post it as an answer, and accept it!  Good find.

Answer (score 3):

After much debugging, reading and learning I found that my problem was pretty simple.  The command

```
sys.modules
```

listed all the modules loaded by python.  When reading that output, I realized that conf was a module that was listed in another module that was loaded and that the module exceptions is used by the base python.  When I renamed the conf to config and exceptions to flow_exceptions everything worked perfectly.

thanks all.  Im going to leave the above unmolested, hopefully my thought process in debugging this can help someone else.

Comment: I have to wait a few more hours before it will let me

Comment: This helped me too (my module creatively named `code`). G'wan - treat yourself to an accepted answer. You've given a modest 26,386 hours for others to chime in.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open project settings, and then "project structure" `FILE->SETTINGS->PROJECT STRUCTURE`
2. Browse to the directory you want to act as base path, and assign it to "sources",
   the imports and autosuggest will start working as per your requirement.

Comment: Tried that yesterday.  Both the gitflow and the tests folders are marked as source folders.

Answer (score 0):

If you really *just* want to do `cd gitflow`, you could use `os.chdir('gitflow')`, but I'm not sure that it's the most elegant solution.

```
import os
os.chdir('path/to/gitflow')
```

** **Edit: What doesn't work for you works for me...** **

```
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Development\\gitflow'
>>> from conf.configmanager import ConfigManager
>>> c = ConfigManager()
```

No errors here.  I'm using Python 3.3 on Windows.

Comment: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gitflow'   Ugh, this shouldn't be this difficult.  Do you know of say a one page tutorial on how to use this thing?

Comment: [Here is](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chdir.htm) a little tutorial on os.chdir, and [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) is a link to the `os` module docs.

Comment: I just did a getcwd (see above edit)  doesn't look like thats my problem because im already in the gitflow folder.  what else could be doing this?  my gitflow folder is set as a source folder, I would imagine that puts it in pythons version of classpath.

Comment: thats odd because it only works for me if i do a gitflow.conf.configmanager and that screws up the thing up because configmanager requires an import from the bottom gitflow folder and it cant find that unless i change import exceptions to import gitflow.exceptions which of course i can't do because that will break the code when i distribute it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried marking your app directory as the source root? Right-click on your app directory in PyCharm and hover on the `Mark Directory As` menu and choose `Source Root`. This may help.

Answer (score 0):

What seemed to work for me is

```
import sys
sys.path.extend(['path/to/whatever'])
```

For some reason it doesn't seem to matter if the directory is marked as 'src' or if the relevant setting for including the src files in Python Console is checked.